# How to call an API running on same EC2 instance but on different port number

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, microservices

I am runnig multiple Node.js servers on one Ec2 Instance , and when i need to call any API that is running on different port of same instance , i need to use AXIOS for calling,I am wondering is this the only way that i can call my API, having known it's running on same EC2 , and is this efficient solution ? please i need guidance

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer this question based on two aspects,

1) The way your application communicating with other application

You can have two ways of doing it. The first one is synchronous, if you have to wait for result from second application and complete the logic in your first application, Then go with this approach. And yes, you can use REST call(using AXION or any REST client).gRpc is another option if you are planning to stream data.

The next one is asynchronous communication, where your application is not waiting for the result from second application(Fire and forget). This can be achieved using a Message queue

2) The way your application is deployed and how it is reffered.

Assuming that you are calling the application using IP:PORT or localhost:PORT(since it is in same VM), I can say that this is not good approach.

Think about a scenario where you need to move one of the application to a different box or you want to scale the application individually. In these cases it would be difficult for you to manage.

Do you have any API gateway or Reverse Proxy or Load-Balancer in front of your application? If yes, call your application through these services.

If you are not sure about the above, please follow the links below,

https://hub.packtpub.com/6-common-use-cases-of-reverse-proxy-scenarios/
https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-does-an-api-gateway-do
https://microservices.io/microservices/news/2015/03/15/deployment-patterns.html

Comment: Hey Sam thanks for detailed response , yes keeping in mind about scalability i am using Load Balancer in front of my EC2 instance

Comment: Make sure that you are using Loadbalancer url for hitting your other application. And also analyse your applications expected load  before deploying in same server

Comment: Sam, i am using route53 in front of my load balancer so no such issue

Comment: Route53 is just a DNS, nothing to with your application load.. I'm talking about your application load and scaling

Comment: "Make sure that you are using Loadbalancer url for hitting your other application" yes sam i  know it's just a DNS Resolver , just answering your first part of question , by the way thanks for your answers but I'm still in doubt about my approach for calling Axios api's for services running on same instance , there must be another efficient way i am looking for instead of calling rest api's